# How to make a Nodejs distributable command line application

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm making a command line application with commander, inquirer and nightwatch as top dependencies. The main purpose of the app is for automation and testing.. Is there any way i can make this distributable instead of publishing it as npm package. I want the same functionality as those cli made with python, where it can be setup, and run on a target machine. is this possible? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two open source projects (PKG and Nexe) that enable you to package your Node.js project into an executable:

https://github.com/zeit/pkg/blob/master/README.md

Or

https://github.com/nexe/nexe/blob/dev/README.md

You can use either one to make an executable of your project.